# Multiple Tables update in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I know this question has already been asked, but I seem to be having issues with implementing the solutions in a project am currently working on. Am trying to update two tables in CodeIgniter, but the framework's escape() database function seems to be doing the wrong thing. Below is a fragment of code am working on:

```
public function update_taxpayer( $usertin, $data ){

    $this->usid = $usertin;

    if( $this->verify_user_tin( $this->usid ) ){

        $this->db->set($data);

        $this->db->where('t.taxpayer_id','tp.id');
        $this->db->where('t.tin', $usertin);
        $this->db->update("tin AS t, taxpayer AS tp");

        $updated_rows = $this->db->affected_rows();

    }

}
```

I get this error while attempting to run an update from my controller:

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'crsirs.tin as t, taxpayer' doesn't exist

UPDATE `tin AS t, taxpayer` AS `tp` SET `t`.`address` = '', `t`.`name` =   'MAPS PROJECT CROSS RIVER STATE', `tp`.`lastModified` = '2016-06-07 13:54:27', `tp`.`city` = '', `tp`.`email` = '', `tp`.`mobile` = '', `tp`.`phone` = NULL WHERE `t`.`taxpayer_id` = 'tp.id' AND `t`.`tin` = '1902406349-0001'

Filename: C:/Program Files/wamp/www/CRSIRS/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

The escape() function seems to be merging the two tables as one in this line `tin AS t, taxpayer` without seeming to escape them properly. Please how do I go about solving this issue?

Comment: I know I can achieve what I wish to achieve using a transaction, but my stubborn self doesn't want to do that!

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: @eggyal Am currently using CodeIgniter 3.0.6

Comment: Try `$this->db->update("tin t, taxpayer tp");`. Though I don't think it will work since it will escape whole string as one table. You'll just have to use transaction.

Comment: `$this->db->from('tin AS t')->join('taxpayer AS tp', 't.taxpayer_id = tp.id')->set($data)->where('t.tin', $usertin)->update();` should do it?

Comment: @eggyal The code above only references the first table in the query! MYSQL generates an 'Unknown column tp.lastModified in field list' error, due to the fact that the the alias 'tp' doesn't exist or isn't executed!

Comment: @TheDrot Yeah I tried that line of code before I posted this S.O.S! Like you said, transactions will be a safer way to go, regrettably!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is an aside but hopefully it will be helpful for you. There's lots of different ways to do this but lets just take a look at this part:

```
public function update_taxpayer( $usertin, $data ){

    $this->usid = $usertin;

    if( $this->verify_user_tin( $this->usid ) ){
```

What is wrong with this? If the user is not verified - nothing else happens. The rest of the method is useless. Therefore that verification - should happen before anything else and in another method. Then you can take the appropriate action. In other words if the user is not verified then you should not be in a method that expects to do two updates.

Comment: Yeah! you're right! I'll do an edit to reflect that! Thanks for pointing that out, i appreciate.

Comment: I think I was overdoing it! I had a verification in my controller and then another one in my model...

Answer (score 0):

Someone rightly said this could be achieved in lots of ways, but what I ended up doing was use query bindings, maybe not the best approach, but it solved what I wanted to do;

```
public function update_taxpayer( $usertin, $data, $data_tp = null ){

    //Tax payers TIN
    $this->usid = $usertin;
    //Rows Affected by update
    $updated_rows = 0;

    /* 
    * Since CodeIgniter ActiveRecord doesn't seem to work with 
    * multiple table updates, we'll attempt to update a user's record
    * using Query Binding.
    */

    $sql = 'UPDATE tin t, taxpayer tp 
                    SET t.address = ?, t.name = ?,
                        tp.street1 = ?, tp.street2 = ?,
                        tp.lastModified = ?,tp.city = ?, tp.email = ?,
                        tp.mobile = ?, tp.phone = ?
                WHERE t.taxpayer_id = tp.id
                    AND t.tin = ?';

    $this->db->query($sql, 
                        array( 
                                $data[0], $data[1], $data[2],
                                $data[3], $data[4], $data[5],
                                $data[6], $data[7], $data[8],$this->usid
                            )
                    );

        $updated_rows = $this->db->affected_rows();

    /**
    * return true on success | false on failure
    **/ 

    return ($updated_rows > 0) ? true : false;

}
```

If you have a better way of doing this, I'd like for you to make us aware! Thanks!!

Comment: I believe with Query Binding the query is also escaped! Are you saying it isn't?

Comment: Whoops you are right, deleted my comment. But still wonder if transactions or using two methods would have benefits....

Comment: @cartalot I had thought of going the way of transaction, but then i realised I'd be faced with the same issue, because the two tables have a relationship and one is reliant on a foreign key!